# Jquery revet to old state while close button click

Tags: jquery

I made a slide show using jquery. it shows the images, and it resize-the div(image holder). everything is ok with this.

once a person navigating to new image, as well he close the pop-up of the slide show. Then later he opens the slide show again, the old size of the slide is not changing, to close the pop-up i am using this function.

```
        $('#close-pop').click(function(){
            $('#slider').hide();
            $('#imgHolder').hide();
            $('#imgHolder img').remove();
        })
```

but no use of from this  code. what i need is, once a person closing the pop-up button, all functions have to reset in to default(primary) state. how can i achive this? if any way to reset the document.ready function, i believe that would be fine..

any ideas?

Comment: Would reloading the page be an option?

Comment: wats the code you use to open the slide show. Do you have the examples live somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your code being executed on $(document).ready again, just put it in a function:

```
var initPage = function() {
    // some actions...
};

$(document).ready(initPage);
```

That way you can execute it again, when the popup is closed:

```
$('#close-pop').click(initPage);
```